# Azure API Management - Customize Token

Tags: azure, api, token, claims

When calling the token endpoint to get an Azure API access token, I want to pass in extra information to be included in the token.  Is that possible?

For example, I want to pass in a locationID to the body when calling:

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/\](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5C)<<tenant id>>/oauth2/v2.0/token

Then I want this locationID to be encoded in the token that I get back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional claims in  Azure AD applications to specify which claims you want in tokens sent to the application.

we can only get the claims with access tokens but we cannot send any extra information like **locationID** while calling the access token.

The following are few of the **v2.0-only optional claims** which can be requested along with access tokens:

- `ipaddr`
- `onprem_sid`
- `pwd_exp`

For complete list of  **v2.0-specific optional claims** set you can refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims#v20-specific-optional-claims-set).

Comment: Yes, but can these optional claims value be customized to specific text or ip address?